# Finding all functions/stored procedures that reference a certain procedure/function?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have been given the task to move reports from SSRS to our internal ASP.Net application and this has involved me re-writing a few functions and a stored procedure to both improve performance, make them output in forms better consumed by the application and make any requested additions to the reports.

What I also need to do is remove the old functions and procedures from the system as I go, before I do this though I want to make sure it will not break anything else. **Is there a way I can go though all the precedures and functions to see if any of them contain references to the ones I will be removing?**

There are thousands of these to go though and I would rather not have to open each one at a time in SSMS to look. So if there is some table I can query or even if there is a .sql file that SQL server is hiding that I could dig though, that would be great.

Comment: Red gate sql search is  good free tool to do this

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`sys.sql_expression_dependencies`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677315.aspx) should give you what you want if you don't want to search through the definition of every single object (especially when references may or may not have schema prefixes).

I think you can get what you want with the following query:

```
SELECT 
    o.name AS ReferencingObject, 
    sd.referenced_entity_name AS ReferencedObject
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies  AS sd
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
    ON o.object_id = sd.referencing_id
WHERE sd.referenced_entity_name = 'my_object_name';
```

Comment: The other problem with brute force parsing is false positives (e.g. the module name is in a comment, a string literal, or part of another object name). But both methods are vulnerable to false negatives (e.g. the call to the module is constructed with dynamic SQL).

Answer (score 0):

Hit up the lovely `sys.sql_modules` DMV:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

IF ( OBJECT_ID( 'tempdb.dbo.#t_ObjectsOfInterest', 'U' ) IS NULL )
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #t_ObjectsOfInterest
    (
        [DBName]                    NVARCHAR( 128 ),
        [ObjectName]                NVARCHAR( 128 ),
        [Definition]                NVARCHAR( MAX )
    );
END;

EXECUTE dbo.sp_MSForEachDB @command1 = '
    USE [?];

    INSERT  INTO #t_ObjectsOfInterest ( [DBName], [ObjectName], [Definition] )
    SELECT  DB_NAME(), OBJECT_NAME( object_id ), definition
    FROM    sys.sql_modules
    WHERE   definition LIKE ''%%dbo.ufn%%'';';
GO

SELECT  *
FROM    #t_ObjectsOfInterest;
GO

--DROP TABLE #t_ObjectsOfInterest;
```

To check any job references:

```
SELECT  sj.name, *
FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps sjs
    ON  sjs.job_id = sj.job_id
WHERE   sjs.command LIKE '%dbo.ufn%';
```

You may not catch everything, such as in-line app code references or other SSIS / SSRS package references, but that should at least remove the actual catalogs from your concerns.

Also, if it's "one of those" functions, you can also use `sys.computed_columns` like `sys.sql_modules` above to find any tables using the function in question as a computed column.

Comment: Oh, please don't recommend `sp_MSForEachDB` - it's unsupported, undocumented, and actually quite buggy in terms of skipping databases. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/

Comment: Not that there is anyting wrong with the replacement Aaron mentions but this one is FAR simpler and actually does MORE.  https://rickbielawski.wordpress.com/2014/07/10/execute-the-same-query-on-all-databases-in-an-instance-alternative-to-sp_msforeachdb/

Answer (score -1):

This appears to work quite well.

```
DECLARE @DBs TABLE (
                    DatabaseName NVARCHAR(128),
                    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
                    )
DECLARE @Objs TABLE (
                    DatabaseName NVARCHAR(128), 
                    Loc NVARCHAR(128), 
                    SchemaObjectName NVARCHAR(128), 
                    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
                    )
                    
DECLARE @LookingFor     NVARCHAR(4000)=N'%SearchValueGoesHere%',
        @intCnt         INT = 1,
        @RecCnt         INT = 0,
        @DatabaseName   NVARCHAR(128),
        @sql            NVARCHAR(max)=N''

INSERT INTO @dbs(DatabaseName)
SELECT 
    name 
FROM 
    sys.databases d
WHERE 
    1=1
AND
    d.name NOT IN ('msdb','master','tempdb','model')
    
SET @recCnt = @@ROWCOUNT

WHILE @intCnt<=@RecCnt
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @databasename = databasename 
    FROM 
        @dbs 
    WHERE 
        id = @intCnt
    PRINT @databasename
    SET @sql = N'USE ' +@databasename+ N' 
    SELECT 
        '''+@DatabaseName+N''' Dbase, ''SQL Modules'' Loc, CONCAT(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id), N''.'', OBJECT_NAME(object_id)) AS SchemaObjectName 
    FROM 
        sys.sql_modules 
    WHERE 
        definition LIKE ''' +@LookingFor +N''' 
    UNION
    SELECT 
        '''+@DatabaseName+N''' Dbase, ''Computed Columns'' Loc, CONCAT(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id), N''.'', OBJECT_NAME(object_id)) AS SchemaObjectName 
    FROM 
        sys.computed_columns 
    WHERE 
        definition LIKE ''' +@LookingFor+N''' 
    UNION
    SELECT 
        '''+@DatabaseName+N''' Dbase, ''Check ConstraINTs'' Loc, CONCAT(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id), N''.'', OBJECT_NAME(object_id)) AS SchemaObjectName 
    FROM 
        sys.check_constraints
    WHERE 
        definition LIKE ''' +@LookingFor+N''' 
    UNION
    SELECT 
        '''+@DatabaseName+N''' Dbase, ''Default ConstraINTs'' Loc, CONCAT(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id), N''.'', OBJECT_NAME(object_id)) AS SchemaObjectName 
    FROM 
        sys.default_constraints
    WHERE 
        definition LIKE ''' +@LookingFor +N''''
    
    PRINT @sql
    
    INSERT INTO @Objs (DatabaseName, Loc, SchemaObjectName)
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    
    SET @intCnt += 1
END

SELECT * FROM @objs
```